# jQuery access child of current parent

Tags: jquery, parent

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to do the following: access the child of the current div's parent ( or in other words: another child of the current div's parent ). My code looks like this ( this is what I tried ):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.head").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().("div.content").slideToggle("normal"); //<- how?
    });
});
</script>

<div class="box">
<div class="head">
    Example
</div>
<div class="content">
    Content here.
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do it this way because then I could just make more boxes the same way without having to add extra js to make it work for every box ( the toggle hide/show of each box's content).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two elements are on the same DOM level then you can use `.siblings()`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".head").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle("normal");
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L5kqs/1/

Your selector needed a `.children()` or a `.find()`:

```
$(this).parent().children(".content").slideToggle("normal");
```

Also note that your selectors will perform faster if you omit the tag names. Only when there are a lot of DOM nodes to search through will that improve performance.

If you would like to read more about `.siblings()` this would be a good start: http://api.jquery.com/siblings

Comment: also note, tag names are required for selectors in IE6

Comment: @happytimeharry: I'm pretty sure no one cares about IE6 support.

Comment: @happytimeharry I just tested with a virtual image of windows XP with IE 6 and no tags in the selectors works fine. I always test my code against IE 6 and I've never had a problem omitting tag names.

Comment: @Jasper my bad... its 5.5 and it something im forced to be concerned with... http://docs.jquery.com/Known_Issues

Comment: Thanks for the answer and extra explanation, helped me a lot and works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.head").click(function() {
        $(this).next("div.content").slideToggle("normal"); //<- easy
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, wouldn't think it was that easy :D. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

If all you're interested in is the element immediately after, use [happytime harry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492992/115845) which uses `.next()`, i.e.:

```
$(this).next(".content").slideToggle("normal");
```

If you're looking for something more general, use one of the following:

```
// Search for elements which are direct children of parent
$(this).parent().children(".content").slideToggle("normal");  

// Search for siblings (same as above, but will not include $(this))
$(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle("normal");

// Search within all descendents of parent
$(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("normal");
```

Comment: find bad: use children, we dont care about all descendants.. siblings bad: use next, we only care about the next sibling not more than one

Comment: Thanks for putting together the possible approaches, helps me on my way of getting a better understanding of jQuery.

Comment: You're very welcome @jasper. Good luck and have fun with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("div.head").click(function() {
         $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("normal"); //<- how?
     });
 });
```

or use siblings

```
 $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle("normal");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use <strike>`.find`</strike> `.children` to get the `div.content`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.head").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children("div.content").slideToggle("normal");
    });
});
```

Or you can use `.siblings`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.head").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings("div.content").slideToggle("normal");
    });
});
```

Comment: find is a waste for his question... use children

Comment: Agreed, `children` is better :-)

Answer (score 0):

something like this should suffice

```
$(".head").bind("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle("normal");
})
```